# RequireJS data-main module callback not invoked

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

My app:

```
define(function bringTheAction() { console.log('Loaded!'); });
```

is optimised and loaded using data-main:

```
<script data-main="src/app" src="lib/require.js"></script>
```

and RequireJS does load the file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app" src="src/app.js"></script>
```

however, the `bringTheAction` callback is never invoked and my app just sits idly.

I can kick things off by doing `require(['src/app']);` in the console or by changing `define` to `require` in the unbuilt code, but:

- from my understanding, it should work as it is; and
- I need to use `define` so the module can be mocked with [Squire](https://github.com/iammerrick/Squire.js/).

In development, the unbuilt code is loaded differently:

```
<script src="lib/require.js"></script>
<script src="src/require.config.js"></script>
<script>require({ /* config applicable to dev */ }, ['src/app'], function () {});</script>
```

and it works like a dream.

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I sort of figured this out, after much confusion.

I noticed the attribute `data-requiremodule="app"` (on the script tag injected by RequireJS) and assume what I need is `data-requiremodule="src/app"`, so that RequireJS knows what to `require` once the file loads.

I'm not sure why it is omitting `src/` on this attribute, since my config is tuned to operate from the directory above `src/` (hence I reference modules by prefixing `src/`, `lib/`, etc).  However, as a fix, I added an alias to the build config, to satisfy RequireJS:

```
paths: { 'app': 'src/app'; }
```

Now that attribute actually points to a module to load.