# RequireJS main require call back never invoked

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've tried [this post's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091712/requirejs-data-main-module-callback-not-invoked) to no avail. No matter what I do, RequireJS's primary callback is never fired. Here's my dependency graph:

```
/module/main.js
    -- /module/mainController.js
        --/vendor/preloadjs
        --/module/itemController.js
        --/module/router.js
            --/vendor/crossroads.js
                --/vendor/signals.js
            --/vendor/hasher.js
                --/vendor/signals.js
```

```js
require.config({
    baseUrl: "script/module",
    paths: {
        signals: "vendor/signals"
    }
});

require(["main", function(){
    console.log("main function!");
}]);
```

The "main" module makes use of js-signals, and actually gets invoked. In fact the entire dependency tree is loaded (confirmed via the web inspector). I have a single entry point for the application. All modules start up and actually run fine. You'd think that if the main application callback doesn't run that one or all of its dependencies would have failed.

I'm sure there is some stupid reason I'm not kicking off the primary require's callback. For the record I've tried using the `requirejs()` method and get the same results.

No files have code in them except for dependencies and console.logs.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you mean you don't get 'main function!' in the console? is the 'script/module/main.js' file loaded ?

Comment: Where is your main file? What files are you including on the page? Is your base URL correct? Are you getting any errors? _Help us help you_.

Comment: No, console doesn't fire "main function!". however, logs from dependencies of main DO get fired. I can add more to the post but I was trying to keep it simple since the problem existed before I added dependencies (i.e. even without any code in main it still doesn't work, despite loading the main.js file).

Comment: @mathletics No, I'm not getting errors. There are other scripts included on the page but they don't interact with require. I'm loading require last, pointing data-main at my main.js file. None of the files involved in the require module system are included via script tags making data-main the only entry point. This is why it's confusing because the entire dependency graph loads. I'll update my question to include more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer my own silliness. The problem is right there in the source. I'm using Angular module injection syntax, and passing the callback as part of the dependency array. Oops. It needs to be the second argument!

Long story short, the code is right, but this is the change:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "script/module",
    paths: {
        signals: "vendor/signals"
    }
});

require(["main"], function(){
    console.log("main function!");
});
```